# JPanel with a painted square doesn't display correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have class `Main` that extends `JFrame`, and class `DrawingPanel` that extends `JPanel`.
`DrawingPanel` fills a square in it's `paintComponent()` method. `Main` is a simple `JFrame`.

`Main` adds an instance of `DrawingPanel` to the `JFrame`.

The problem is:

If I don't set a layout for `Main`, the square in the `DrawingPanel` gets displayed correctly.
If I do set a layout for `Main`, suppose `FlowLayout()`, the square doesn't get displayed, but I know the `paintComponent()` method in `DrawingPanel` does run, because I printed something to the console from inside this method to check. Also, the panel's black border apears.

Code:

Class DrawingPanel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,50,50,50);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.fill(rect);
    }   

}
```

Class Main:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel;

    public Main(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());//If I delete this line, the square gets
                                      //displayed correctly. Otherwise, the panel
                                      //and it's black border are displayed without
                                      //a black square inside of them.

        panel = new DrawingPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        add(panel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I don't set a layout for Main, square displays correctly. If I do
>   set a layout for Main, suppose FlowLayout(), the square doesn't get
>   displayed.

- Always use a LayoutManager: As you are working with `FlowLayout`
- Set the preferred size of the component as `FlowLayout` obeys the preferred size of component to be added to the Container. Extending the component and overriding the `getPreferredSize(Dimenstion)` is preferable for providing size hints, as it allows the component to be sized according to it's content.
- Don't use JFrame's `setSize(Dimension)`. Instead call `pack()` when you are done adding all of your component from your use case. The pack method sizes the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes.
- `setVisible(true)` on frame should be invoked after adding all of your component and also after invoking `pack()` on `JFrame`.
- And don't forget to put the GUI rendering task inside the EDT. Even the `JFrame.setVisible(true)` should be executed inside the EDT. Make use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` for this case.
- As @camickr has suggested, don't forget to check out [Performing Custom Painting Steps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) to see all of the above recommendation in action.

**Check out official tutorial page**:

1. [How to use FLowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)
2. [Solving Common Layout Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html)

Comment: What's wrong with the way I used FlowLayout()? I checked the tutorials, nothing I did seems wrong.

Comment: +1, and don't forget to read the section from the Swing tutorial on `Perfoming Custom Painting`. The "step 2 example" will show you how to structure your code using all the suggestions from above.

Comment: As i have said, you haven't set any preferred Size to the `DrawingPanel` so it will use the default size hint: around (2, 2) to set the size

Comment: @Sage By 'default size hint' you mean, default size for a JPanel?

If so, how come when I add a button to a JPanel and then add the JPanel to a JFrame, the JPanel automatically has the right size to contain the button, but when a square is drawn inside a JPanel and not a button, I have to set the size of the JPanel manually?

Comment: @Josh, For, `JButton`, `JLabel`  Swing will smartly set their size hints according to their content: text, image ect.

Comment: I know that a JButton will have it's size set automatically according to it's content. But what about a JPanel? If a JPanel contains a JButton, then the JPanel automatically has the right size to contain it, but when a JPanel contains a Rectangle, I have to set the size of the JPanel manually so the Rectangle will fit. Am I correct?

Comment: @Josh, have you read the section from the tutorial on `Performing Custom Painting` yet? Did you add a System.out.println(panel.getPreferredSize()) statement to your code? Also, the default size of a JPanel is (0, 0). However, when you add the DrawingPanel to the content pane the preferred size of the content pane is (10, 10) I belive (not 2, 2). This is because the FlowLayout adds a gap of 5 pixels before/after each component added to the panel.

Comment: @Josh, `I have to set the size of the JPanel manually so the Rectangle will fit.` no you don't set the size manually. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size. That was already explained to you in the second bullet of the original answer. You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method!!! It is also explained in the "Custom Painting" tutorial. Have you read the tutorial yet??? Pay attention to the answers given!

Comment: @camickr, yes it is `10 x 10`. I should not have any confusion over your belief, should i? ;)